# How to alter search api autocomplete to exact match?

Tags: 8, search

I have installed search api autocomplete module. I have configured it also but the requirement is to it should search only 'starts with word'. now the result is searching if a word present in mid of a sentence/title. But i need only starts with title/sentence. I checked in backed configuration for the same but for autocomplete i didn't find any such configs. Is there any way to alter the search any out-of-the-box feature available in backend only.